# How are AppStore in-app region prices calculated?

Tags: ios, app-store

I want to publish an app that contains an annual in-app subscription. The price of this subscription should be 150 USD + Apple's commission. So I set Subscription Price on App Store Connect to 194.99 USD and allowed automatically recalculate the price for all regions.

However, after performing `SKProductsRequest` for region Germany, I've found that `SKProduct` price is 214.99 EUR, which anyhow cannot be 194.99 USD. I checked my in-app page on App Store, and I saw that for all EUR-currency regions, the auto-calculated price is 214.99 EUR.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8jU1.png)

Converting with the current rate, 194.99 USD is 176.61 EUR. Moreover, when I select 179.99 EUR on App Store Connect page, it's recalculated to 164.99 USD.

Could anyone please explain this calculation?

Comment: This is not really a programming question. This is about Apple's App Store pricing logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say hello to VAT:

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/

> For example, if you decide to lower the subscription price for users
>   in Germany, the revenue you’ll receive will be the purchase price
>   minus the European Union’s value added tax (VAT) and minus Apple’s
>   commission. The default pricing in the App Store Connect pricing tool
>   is inclusive of applicable taxes that Apple collects and remits. For
>   more information, review Schedule 2 of the Apple Developer Program
>   License Agreement, which describes territories that have different tax
>   treatments.

This is likely to be flagged as a non-programming issue since it is app store specific. May want to see if you can x-post to the appropriate forum to aid people with this question in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, this isn't programming question, however SO contains a lot of app-store non-programming questions with high reputation, so I believe my specific question adds value to SO, as it wasn't answered before.